# Why is form-data not in req.body?

Tags: reactjs, postman, form-data

I have a project that uses REACT and form-data, and the form-data is set from **within** the REACT client and processed using the req.body in the API without issue.  However, when I use Postman the req.body is empty - why is the form-data req.body empty?

## Postman form-data

The form-data information I am trying to send via postman is a variable named "folder" and a file named "One.png".

This is how it looks before I send:

[image]

## REACT API - 1

Here is the basic API call:

```js
router.post('/:userId/images', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), async (req, res) => {
  var userId = req.params.userId;
});
```

### req.body is empty in REACT API

When I set a break point and then make the Postman call, the req.body is empty:

[image]

## REACT API - 2

Here is the SAME API call but now using the req.on(...) function...

```js
router.post('/:userId/images', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), async (req, res) => {
  var userId = req.params.userId;

  req.on('data', async (data) => {
    console.log('DATA', data.toString());

    return res.status(200).json('ok');
   }
});
```

### req.on(...) has data ?

The req.on(...) function, the form-data is present

[image]

I noticed a couple of other posts inquired if Postman was indeed sending the data and to provide snapshots

#### request headers

[image]

#### request data

[image]

How can I use req.body to get form data ?

## TRY 1

I added Multer to my project, hoping it would solve the problem.

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

...

router.post('/:userId/images', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), upload.array('imageArray'), async (req, res) => {
```

Now I am getting the 'variables' now in the req.body, but still no imageArray AND the req.on(...) is never hit

[image]

Comment: Check `req.files`, not `req.body`

Comment: with the multer added?

Comment: Yes, with multer... you need middleware to handle multipart form data, otherwise you have to manually consume it yourself as you observed.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Hey https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts - if you thought this was a good question, would you up vote it?  ( I tried to be as thorough as possible when posing the question and providing details )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding multer dependency to the project

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
  },
```

Bring it into the project

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
```

change the API to use the multer 'upload'

```js
router.post('/:userId/images', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), upload.array('imageArray'), async (req, res) => {
```

And lastly, check the correct values as Patrick Roberts suggested:

```js
  console.log('req.body', JSON.stringify(req.body));
  console.log('req.files', JSON.stringify(req.files));
```

output:

```js
req.body {"variables":"{folder:\"test\"}"}
routes/api/user/users.js:665
req.files [{"fieldname":"imageArray","originalname":
```

Comment: For future reference, in order to reduce the amount of guesswork you seem to be going through, always [read the relevant documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount) before posting a question, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Patrick... I just hunted around and found another example that just happened to use multer during a file upload... I didn't realize that the "files" object was associated with multer as the files were passed into the API as a parameter of multer - thank you for the pointer !